# p-retry making my test unlaunchable wonder why and how to fix that

Tags: javascript, jestjs

So my problem is that since I implemented the p-retry lib (retry call api X times you want). On the `localhost:3000` work fine but when I launch the tests I got the following return:

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

    Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

    By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
    For information about custom transformations, see:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

    Details:

    /project/node_modules/p-retry/index.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import retry from 'retry';
                                                                                      ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

      1 | import fetch from 'node-fetch';
    > 2 | import pRetry, { AbortError } from 'p-retry';
        | ^
      3 |
      4 | import HttpsProxyAgent from 'https-proxy-agent';
      5 | const proxyAgent = process.env.HTTPS_PROXY

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1728:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (services/medVir/http.ts:2:1)
```

So I guess it's probably an error of config so this is my jest.config.js :

```
const nextJest = require('next/jest');

const createJestConfig = nextJest({
    // Provide the path to your Next.js app to load next.config.js and .env.local files in your test environment
    dir: './',
});

// Add any custom config to be passed to Jest
const customJestConfig = {
    clearMocks: true,
    collectCoverage: true,
    coverageDirectory: 'coverage',
    coveragePathIgnorePatterns: [
        '/node_modules/',
        '__tests__/utils/',
        '/public/',
    ],
    moduleNameMapper: {
        '\\.(css|less)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',
        '\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$':
            'identity-obj-proxy',
        '^-!svg-react-loader.*$': '<rootDir>/config/jest/svgImportMock.js',
    },
    testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
    testMatch: [
        // "**/__tests__/**/*.[jt]s?(x)",
        '**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[tj]s?(x)',
    ],
    testPathIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/', '__tests__/utils/'],
    // transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!(p-retry)/)'],
    verbose: true,
    transform: {
        // Use babel-jest to transpile tests with the next/babel preset
        // https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#transform-objectstring-pathtotransformer--pathtotransformer-object
        '^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$': [
            'babel-jest',
            {
                presets: [
                    [
                        '@babel/preset-env',
                        {
                            targets: {
                                node: 'current',
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                    '@babel/preset-typescript',
                    '@babel/preset-react',
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
    setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/.jest/setEnvVars.js'],
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.js'],
};

// createJestConfig is exported this way to ensure that next/jest can load the Next.js config which is async
// module.exports = customJestConfig;
module.exports = createJestConfig(customJestConfig);
```

I tried a lot of different config and implementation but nothing to do... still the same error so I`m wondering if the problem could be something else.
Something sure since I change axios to node-fetch with p-retry (to handle request and retry then) my tests just stoped to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I come to give you a solution for people which crossing the same problem as me. So I didn't fix the lib or found jest config to handle the weird behavior so I made my own function to do kind of the same thing :

- Which is recalling X times the same call api if the timeout is reach

code :

```
const makeAPICall = async ({
    url,
    body = '',
    method = 'GET',
    type = 'TEXT',
}: IApi) => {
    // init path
    const path = new URL(url);
    const timeout = 28_000;
    let myInit = {
        method,
        timeout,
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
    };
    if (method !== 'GET') myInit = { ...myInit, ...{ body: body } };
    const res = await fetch(path.href, myInit);
    switch (type) {
        case 'TEXT':
            return res.text();
        default:
            return res.json();
    }
};

const sleep = (ms: number) =>
    new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(), ms));

const makeApiRetry: any = async (args: IArgs, retries = 3, old_n = 0) => {
    let n = old_n;

    return makeAPICall(args).catch(async () => {
        if (n < retries) {
            n++;
            // console.log('Retrying request', n, `waiting ${1000 * n} `, args.url);
            await sleep(1000 * (n + 1));
            return makeApiRetry(args, retries, n);
        } else {
            return Promise.reject('Too many retries : error timeout');
        }
    });
};

// Get node-fectch
export const getApiRoute = async (body: string) =>
    await makeApiRetry({
        url: `/apiRoute`,
        body,
        method: 'GET',
        type: 'JSON',
    });
```